# Can't include jQuery Datatables via webpack bower components

Tags: jquery, datatables, bower, webpack

```
require('datatables'); does not work
```

I'm having a hard time trying to include jQuery-Datatables as a webpack module from bower, the current settings work with other bower components, here part of the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        )
    ],
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin` expects a single string entry in the `main` field, and the `bower.json` of datatables declares an array:

```
"main": [
        "media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
        "media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
]
```

There is a whole discussion, about why it's like that [here](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/3).

(shameless plug)

I have created a [bower-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin), that you may want to look at. It is still under a development, but should handle arrays in `main` field. Additionally if you find any issues with it, please feel free to report a bug, and I'll try to get it fixed.